# www-data cannot create files even though it owns the folder

Tags: permissions, docker

I'm setting up a web server running in a Docker container based on Debian 9.3 and I'm trying to configure the tmp folder but I can't get www-data to create files in it.

The tmp and all sub directory are owned by www-data:www-data and tried setting everything to 777 to no avail. I've logged in as www-data to make sure files can't be created. I don't have SELinux installed. If the file already exist www-data has no problem writing to it.

```
www-data@8c22a401af40:/srv/www/is/app/tmp/cache/persistent$ ls -lah
total 16K
drwxrwxrwx  2 www-data www-data 4.0K Jan 31 21:37 .
drwxrwxrwx 20 www-data www-data 4.0K Jan 31 21:37 ..
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data 2.8K Jan 31 19:08 myapp_cake_core_file_map
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data    7 Jan 31 21:38 test


www-data@8c22a401af40:/srv/www/is/app/tmp/cache/persistent$ touch test2
touch: cannot touch 'test2': Permission denied
```

Edit:
I forgot to mention it but I've also set 777 and changed ownership to www-data for all the parent folder.

Edit2:
Output of `root@8c22a401af40:/# getfacl -R /srv/www/`:

```
# file: srv/www//is/app/tmp
# owner: www-data
# group: www-data
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx
```

The output is the same for all 1271 files.

Also while getting this output I realized I couldn't reproduce this problem at home. To be sure I ssh'ed to my machine at work and rebuilt the container from scratch and tried again and got the same result. That machine runs Debian 9 and my laptop runs Mac OS 10.12.

Edit3:
I tried on another machine running Debian 9 and again couldn't reproduce. I'm suspecting now the problem lies with the host rather than my docker image.

Comment: What are the permissions for each of the remaining directories (`/srv/www/is/app`)?

Comment: Also 777 and owned by www-data, edited the question!

Comment: What is the output of `getfacl -R /srv/www/`?

Comment: Added the output to the question and discovered that I don't have this problem on my laptop. Also, not sure if that matters but I had to install acl before running the command.